# What does "([%_])" regex mean in Java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

What does the following code/regex do in Java. I am looking at code written by another dev, but I can't make what the following regex does? Besides is it a well-known regex-pattern to use circle and square brackets ?

```
str.replaceAll("([%_])", "\\$1");
```

Comment: Just replaces any `%` or `_` with a `$1` substring. Same as `.replace("%", "$1").replace("_", "$1")`. Perhaps, it was meant to be `str.replaceAll("([%_])", "\\\\$1");` so that `$1` could be parsed as a backreference, and then it would be escaping `%` and `_`.

Comment: The brackets and symbols have special meanings in regex. For instance `(` opens a capturing group and `[` a set of symbols.

Comment: It matches a `%` or `_` character.  This line of code will add a backslash to either one of those characters.  It looks like you're preparing a String to go into an SQL `like` condition, where either of those characters would need to be escaped, due to their special meaning in SQL.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem What does `$1` mean in SQL? How can we use `$1` for both `_` and `%` ?

Comment: `$1` doesn't mean anything special in SQL, but in the `replaceAll` method it means "the thing you found".  So your line of Java replaces your `_` or `%` with "backslash followed by the thing you found".

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Gotcha. So its bad code on the other dev's part. How would I replace `%` or `_` with `\%` or `\_` I want to replace those wildcards by adding backslash to it.

Comment: It's not bad code. It already does what you want.

Comment: I found the answer by @SebastienHelbert so short, precise, and to the point, that I thought that it deserved to have a question.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern just replaces any `%` or `_` with a `$1` substring and is the same as `.replace("%", "$1").replace("_", "$1")`.

Perhaps, it was meant to be `str.replaceAll("([%_])", "\\\\$1");` so that `$1` could be parsed as a backreference, and then it would be escaping `%` and `_`.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9FANNj):

```
System.out.println("% and _".replaceAll("([%_])", "\\$1"));    // => $1 and $1
System.out.println("% and _".replaceAll("([%_])", "\\\\$1"));  // => \% and \_
```

Answer (score 0):

This code just escapes every `'%'` or `'_'` character by prefixing them with a backslash.